# Micro Profile Openapi 3.0 document generation at maven build time

Tags: java, maven, plugins, openapi, microprofile

Hi am trying to generate API documentation by scanning all openapi annotation which we used in java at maven build time to generate json or YAML rather than generating in Runtime in liberty server.Its working fine with runtime.

maven

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>microprofile-openapi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Am looking for any maven plugin to generate Api document at Buildtime for openApi